# I am getting following Error message while creating IBM db2 procedure

Tags: database, db2, db2-400, db2-luw

What is wrong with the following code?

```
PROCEDURE DATETYPE DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
DECLARE @DateType TABLE
    ( LABEL CHAR(30) ,
    Value VARCHAR(1) );

DECLARE C CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR;

INSERT
    INTO
        @DateType
    VALUES ('Paid Dates Only',
    'P') INSERT
        INTO
            @DateType
        VALUES('Incurred Dates with Paid',
        'S') SELECT
            *
        FROM
            @DateType;

OPEN C;
END
```

I am using db2 and gets the following error:

> SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "( LABEL CHAR(30) ,   Value VARCHAR(1) )" was found following " ".  Expected tokens may include:  "E @DateType TABLE   ".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.21.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wichever DB2 it is (db2-400 or db2-luw) `DECLARE xx TABLE` is not DB2 SQL PL syntax

Btw if I understand it well your code can be replaced with a view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DATETYPE (LABEL, VALUE) as (
    VALUES 
    ('Paid Dates Only', 'P'),
    ('Incurred Dates with Paid', 'S')
)
```

edit:since it has to be a prodecure, then you can use

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DATETYPE ()
     RESULT SETS 1
     LANGUAGE SQL
   BEGIN
       DECLARE DATAS CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR 
            VALUES 
            ('Paid Dates Only', 'P'),
            ('Incurred Dates with Paid', 'S');
       OPEN DATAS;
   END
```

Comment: I need to have this inside a stored procedure so that I can call this in SSRS. I am new to db2 and not sure of syntax.. I assumed it would be like what I would write in sql server!

Comment: Thank you for your help